# Using awk, combine multiple key-data in one file with multiple key-values from a second file?

Tags: awk, multiple-columns, key-value, substitution

data.txt (data;key;data;key):

```
Data1;Key1;DataA;KeyA
Data2;Key2;DataB;KeyB
Data3;Key3;DataC;KeyA
Data4;Key2;DataC;KeyB
Data3;Key1;DataB;KeyA
Data2;Key5;DataA;KeyB
```

keys.txt (key;value;key;value;key;value):

```
Key1;10;keyA;100;keyB;1000;
Key2;20;keyA;200;keyB;2000;
Key3;30;keyA;300;keyB;3000;
Key4;30;keyA;400;keyB;4000;
```

Hence, KeyA on the same row as Key1 gives `KeyA=100`.
Similarly, KeyA on the same row as Key2 gives `KeyA=200`.
Similar procedure for KeyB.

Output (append the appropriate two values from keys.txt to each row of data.txt):

```
Data1;Key1;DataA;KeyA;10;100
Data2;Key2;DataB;KeyB;20;2000
Data3;Key3;DataC;KeyA;30;300
Data4;Key2;DataC;KeyB;20;2000
Data3;Key1;DataB;KeyA;10;100
Data2;Key5;DataA;KeyB;-;-
```

For example, the first row in data.txt contains Key1 and KeyA, hence find the row in keys.txt which contains key1 and 
append its corresponding value, then append either KeyA or KeyB, in this  case KeyA which is 100. So KeyB from the first row in `keys.txt` is not 
used for anything in the first row of the output.

The last row in `data.txt` contains Key5, but in `keys.txt` there is no Key5, therefore append a default ;-;-

Comment: **Oops, you forgot to post your code!** StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on improving this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save this to a file called `program`:

```
BEGIN { FS=";"; }
NR==FNR {
    data[$1] = $2;
    data[$1, toupper($3)] = $4;
    data[$1, toupper($5)] = $6;
    next;
}
{
    one = data[$2];
    two = data[$2, toupper($4)];
    print $0 ";" (one ? one : "-") ";" (two ? two : "-");
}
```

Then, call `awk -f program keys.txt data.txt`.

Comment: Nice with a pure awk solution, however, for me it doesn't work?: ./b: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./b: line 1: `BEGIN { FS=";"; }'

Comment: @Markus Which version of `awk`?

Comment: GNU Awk 4.0.1
Btw, I don't see where the input files (data.txt and keys.txt) are in your solution?

Comment: @Markus Sorry, I thought it was obvious: `awk -f program keys.txt data.txt`.

Comment: Markus - you've asked multiple awk questions and received multiple answers and you didn't know how to use the posted script AND want the command in the answer so you can copy/paste it??? Michael - `one = data[$2];...print $0 ";" (one ? one : "-")...` creates elements in `data` and so uses more memory than necessary and it will fail if/when `data[$2]` has a value that evaluates numerically to zero. You should be doing `one = ($2 in data ? data[$2] : "-");...print $0 ";" one ...` instead.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for pointing out this horrible design flaw of `awk` to me. As far as zero values are concerned you are certainly right.

Comment: You're welcome. That's not a design flaw, though. Creating and initializing array elements when first used is completely consistent with creating and initializing scalar variables when first used. To do anything different for array elements than is done for scalars would be a design flaw.

Comment: @EdMorton I beg to differ. It makes sense to create a variable, scalar or otherwise, as soon as it is assigned to. But I see no reason to create it just because it is referenced.

Comment: Everything else aside, it's more useful than otherwise. Today we write `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $0 in a' file1 file2` to print the lines from file2 that existed in file1 without **needing to** make up values to assign to a[$0] (which may not even be desirable) and we write tests like `a[x] == 0 && a[x] == ""` (or `var == 0 && var == ""`) to identify uniinitialized array elements or scalars (particularly useful when testing for optional function arguments). If they weren't created, typed as numeric-string, and initialized to zero-or-null when first referenced then we couldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The simple script may meet your requirement. Use `awk` to parse and extract the keys in data.txt. And you may find the corresponding key values in the keys.txt.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                  

while read i; do

  echo $i | awk '{printf "%s;",$1}'
  key_no=$(echo $i | awk -F';' '{print $2}')
  key_a_b=$(echo $i | awk -F';' '{print $4}')

  grep $key_no keys.txt | awk -v key="$key_a_b" -F';' '{
      if (key=="KeyA") {printf "%d;%d\n",$2,$4}
      if (key=="KeyB") {printf "%d;%d\n",$2,$6}
    }'

  [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne 0 ] && echo "-;-"

done < data.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an awesome solution that works great, combining bash with awk. :)

Comment: No, that is a terrible idea and contains multiple insidious bugs. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some, but not all, of the issues in this answer.